# Is it possible to have a workflow that hides git upstream history?

Tags: git, workflow, gitlab

We are setting up git where there are several private repos for internal use that all contribute to a single external product (e.g. pc repo, plastics repo, technical docs repo, etc). These fall under the same group or namespace (we are using Gitlab) and are where ongoing work is branched from.

We would like to have another, single repo that at release time, all of these other repos will feed into so that a customer can access this single repo to see releases for the product. i.e. this repo will contain coommits that will consist of plastics, PCB, docs and so on, altogether.

I had thought I could do this by simply setting up the internal repos as readonly remotes to the external repo would do the trick. As far as mixing the content together and issuing a release this does work, howver it also drags in the history of all the internal repos which we **don't** want the customer to see. Is there such a workflow or functionality within git/Gitlab that allows me to achieve something like this?

Basically I would like to allow linking between internal and external to allow releases to customers to be managed by pulls from the different internal repos and a push to the single external repo so the release manager has an easy job. But I don't want the customer seeing all our internal changes and IP, etc.

Maybe I am thinking about this the wrong way?

Something like these 3 repos where the dev history does not cross the dashed blue line and J and L are releases for customers to use:

[image: Something like this]